# New window not receiving session/cookies

Tags: php, javascript, window

I'm linking to another page that is opening in a window.

here is the link:

```
<a href='#' onclick=\"window.open('linkadress.php here."','targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=200,height=200')\" />
```

Now when i open the file, i want it to be showed to people that are logged in, which is where i encounter my problem..
I'm including my files to the login script, and using both session_start(); and ob_start(); on the page opened in the window, but it just wont use my cookies in there..

Does anyone know why this is happening?

- Edit: Nobody knows what to do ? :O

Comment: check out if there is a cookie in that window with a tool (ex: web developer plugin for firefox). btw does it work if you don't open it in a new window ?

Comment: The cookie isnt there. im trying to echo it with php
And yes it works when i open the file in the main window

Comment: You said that it works fine in IE, but not in firefox, try it in Google Chrome, if it doesn't work there, then maybe the browser is using some "sandbox" technology ...